# Dynamic Dropdow not population with Onchange event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

im using Jquery Ajax For Populate the Dynamic Dropdown but its working for only first row of JSTL-foreach iteration of table.its not working for other rows except first row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roleId').on('change', function() {
        var selectedValue = $('#roleId').val();
      $.ajax({
            url : 'FrontController?s=user&action=ROLES&roleId='+selectedValue,
            dataType: "json",   
            success : function(data) {
                var dropdown21 = $('#userIdEmail');
                  $('>option', dropdown21).remove();

                   $.each(data, function(i, val) {


                      var content="";
                     //for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                             content +='<option value="'+data[i].userId.toString()+'">'+data[i].userName.toString()+'</option>';
                        // };
                          $("#userIdEmail").append(content);


                }); //end of each 

            } 

        });//end of ajax
});
});//end of ready
```

My Html Code

```
 <td style="text-align: left; border: 1px solid black" ><select
                    id="roleId" name="roleId" class="text">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <c:forEach var="role" items="${roleDetails}">
                            <option value="${role.roleId }">${role.roleDescription}</option>
                        </c:forEach>


                </select>

                <select id="userIdEmail" name="userIdEmail" class="text">
                 <option >Select</option>
               </select>
                </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Post html also. Is it dropdown share with the same ID name?? ID name must be unique.

Comment: try to provide jsfiddle for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(document.body).on('change','.text', function() {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();   
            var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'FrontController?s=user&action=ROLES&roleId='+selectedValue,
            dataType: "json",   
            success : function(data) {
                var dropdown21 = $('.userIdEmail1');
                $this.next('select').children('option').remove();

                   $.each(data, function(i, val) {


                      var content="";
                     //for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                             content +='<option value="'+data[i].userId.toString()+'">'+data[i].userName.toString()+'</option>';
                        // };
                          $this.next('select').append(content);


                }); //end of each 

            } 

        });//end of ajax

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is because you are using the same ID name. Try use the solution below:

1) change the dropdown id name(roleId) into class.

```
 class="roleId"
```

2) Use this js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('change','.roleId', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var nextSelect = $(this).next();
  $.ajax({
        url : 'FrontController?s=user&action=ROLES&roleId='+selectedValue,
        dataType: "json",   
        success : function(data) {

               nextSelect.empty();
               $.each(data, function(i, val) {


                  var content="";
                 //for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                         content +='<option value="'+data[i].userId.toString()+'">'+data[i].userName.toString()+'</option>';
                    // };
                      nextSelect.append(content);


            }); //end of each 

        } 

    });//end of ajax
});
});
```

*p/s : please share the HTML snippet together.*

Comment: Did you change already the class name. put `roleId` into `class="text roleId"`

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, just put `class="text roleId"` into your first select dropdownlist. Not the second one. Only for select that have name `roleId`

Comment: Weird, that code will make populate select with particular rows only. Did you change everything that mentioned? like class name. See updated code.

Comment: Can you put edited code you made, then share here(in a file avoid from being posted unrelated answer). Wanna see the edited code.

Comment: finally i did something now its working and thank u so much for your response . im posting my answer

Comment: @Meghana , did't realize that inside success block, the $(this) not captured the previous selector. Anyway, glad it worked out. :)